# Subgroups and normal-subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I have that $H$ is subgroup of a group $G$, and $K$ normal subgroup of a group $G$. I need to prove that $H\cap K$ is not a normal subgroup of $K$ if $G=K=S_3$ where $S_3$ are permutation with 3lines, and $H$ is generated with permutation (12)(3). I tried to prove that the order of $K$ is not divisible with the order of $H\cap K$, but i get nowhere with that.

Comment: What is a "permutation with 3lines"?

Comment: It is the symmetric group on a set of three elements, the group of all permutations of a three-elements.

Comment: means three symbols right??

Comment: Yes, three symbols.

Comment: I don't understand the role of $K$ if later you assume $K=G$.

Comment: That is written in text, i don't understand either

Comment: As it is, it seems you just need to prove that $H$ is not normal in $S_3$.

Comment: Yes, and when i try to prove that it is not normal in G i get (12)(3) but that belongs G?

Comment: $H=\{(),(12)(3)\}$, so you need to find a $\sigma \in S_3$ such that $\sigma (12)(3) \sigma^{-1} \notin H$.

Comment: So anything i get that is different from (12)(3) would mean that H is not normal in G?

Comment: $H\unlhd S_3 \stackrel{(def.)}{\iff} \forall h\in H, \forall \sigma \in S_3, \sigma h \sigma^{-1} \in H$.

Comment: Ok, that is the same way i did it. Thanks

Comment: @MilicaKoprivica, may I ask if Koprivica is a surname or a nickname?

Answer (score 0):

HINT

$(13)(12)(13)^{-1}=(13)(12)(13)=(23)\not\in H\cap K$ hence $H\cap K$ is not normal in $G=S_3$

Comment: Ok, i get you used  formula to prove that something is not a subgroup. But why you used (13) and (12)?

Comment: If you may, see again the definition of the normal subgroup. I used $(12)$ since $H\cap K=\langle (12)\rangle$ and I chose $(13)$ since it works